# can we use ねー as a question?

Tags: grammar, slang, colloquial-language, contractions, spoken-language

I've read that people usually change ない to ねー to make it more manly, like:

したくないよ becomes したくねーんだ

So basically i often heard questions ending with ない but have not heard anyone end a question with ねー

Hence this question: can we use ねー as a question?

Example:

[There's a party tomorrow]

明日、行かない？ converted to 明日、行かねー？

what about this: 明日、行かねーんだ？

Comment: I've seen this used as questions in games and manga, but outside that I don't really have a proper answer. So I'll let someone with a better answer, answer.

Comment: “People _usually_ change ない to ねー” sounds like an exaggeration to me.  For example, some male speakers just do not use ねー.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi ok i'll keep that in mind

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3746

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you say, ねー is a (very) informal, rather masculine, way of replacing ない at the end of words.

Works for both verbs:

行かない →　行かねー

and い-adjectives (which are kind-of-verbs anyway, but let's not get into that debate here):

危ない【あぶない】→　アブねー

in fact it also works with other "-a" kanas. E.g:

ヤバい　→　ヤベー

Adding のだ/んだ as you do in your example is only warranted if you are making it a strong assertion: 行かねーんだよ！

And frankly, unless you spend your Saturday evenings loitering on the sidewalks of Sentâ-gai, you probably don't want to speak like that.

**As a question**, it works just the same as the ない form (sort of a loose equivalent to the "isn't it" form in English):

行かないか？　→　行かねーかー？

... is "grammatically" correct (with or without "明日"), but rare (sounds really rough/rude to me). Probably because ねー is a fairly colloquial form, which is only acceptable because it refers to yourself (and thus "俺が行かねー" is OK), but when you are asking the question form, you are using it on *somebody else*. If that person is standing in front of you, no matter how close you are, this could sound rather rude. Only acceptable context I can think of, would be referring to an abstract third-party:

誰か行かねーか？

This aside, the question form of ねー would mostly be used for **rhetorical** questions:

行かねーかー/行かねーかなー ("Hmnn... Should I go?")

or "semi-rhetorical" questions like:

アブねーなー？/アブねーかなー ("isn't it kinda dangerous?")

Comment: what about just this: 明日、行かねー？ (rising intonation i suppose..) is it possible.., weird.., or just plain wrong?

Comment: As I said, it's not wrong (and therefore possible), the right intonation would be quite hard to pull off without sounding weird. And this most definitely would be reserved to very very familiar language (probably wouldn't even use it on a girlfriend). As often with colloquial Japanese, you are better off staying away until you've heard it enough that you are confident about its use.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with Dave. Sounds too rough. As a rule, if you haven't mastered the feel for a phrase, just like "fuck" in English with non-natives, you should avoid it.

Comment: A related note, not worth a full answer: turning ない into ねぇ is also dialectical: in the Tôhoku area, the sound "あい" is often rendered "えぇ". For example, "行かないか？" would become "行がねぇが？". However, I wouldn't suggest you try that unless you already have a strong Tôhoku intonation…

Comment: Was 'other "か-family" kanas' a typo? I can't see what it means. I guess you meant to say that this `ai -> ei` sound change works in other places outside i-adjectives, usch as みたい -> みてー. Is that it?

Comment: @Boaz: not quite a typo, but an attempt to say "kana ending in '-a'"... Upon re-reading, I just realised how confusing it is. Fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: @Axioplase how do you type that small え?

Comment: @Pacerier: depends on your IME. But generally 'x' followed by the kana you want.

Comment: @Axioplase sry i digress, which IME do you use?

Comment: @Dave: Isn't みたい a better example then? Since やばい is already an i-adjective.

Comment: @Boaz: actually, i did mean "other -a kanas for i-adjectives"... On conjugated verbs, huh... I'm not really sure it is common usage (or even usage altogether). But if you know it is, I'll definitely edit accordingly. When you say みたい, do you mean the volitional form of 見る? Don't think I've ever heard みてー used instead, but it very well could be me...

Comment: @Dave: no, I mean the na-adjective construction みたい. :)

Comment: Pacerier: I use skk in scim. And I used "xe" to input "ぇ".

Comment: @Boaz: Ah ok. But in that case, can you give me a full example? I'll be happy to add it, but I have never encountered it myself, so not sure what's a good example. To me "みてー" on its own would sound way too much like an imperative form of the verb, drawn out... But there might be clearer examples?

Comment: @Dave: Can't think of anything great right now, but there are tons of examples at [Google](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&ie=UTF-8&q=%22%E3%81%BF%E3%81%A6%E3%83%BC%E3%81%AA%22), some of them quite weird (アトムみてーな頭？), and many of them right rude (which is to be expected with みてー being very informal).