# What does こまけー mean?

Tags: slang, register, phonology

Does anybody have a clue what `こまけー` might mean? Below are some sentences for context and the phrase as it's used:

> まじめでおカタい感じの女子大生は、やたらとわたしを目を敵にしてきた。わたしが何をやっても文句をつけてくる。「しょうゆの向きは、こうじゃなくてこう！」って **こまけー** んだよ!

Comment: It could be a colloquial way of writing 「細{こま}かいよ！」 maybe?

Comment: "Komakai" and "komake"... I didn't see that before, now I feel silly. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Edo-speak (江戸言葉) or rough speak in present Japanese, a sequence of a vowel followed by a high vowel is often contracted to one long vowel. `こまけー`'s original form is `[細]{こま}かい` 'detailed'. In this case, it is claiming that the other person cares too much about subtle things.

There are other patterns as well:

> ai → ee, 　　[高]{たか}い → たけえ
>   ei → ee, 　　[競]{けい}[馬]{ば} → けえば　　　　(Standard pronunciation; written as けいば)
>   oi → ee, 　　[面]{おも}[白]{しろ}い → おもしれえ
>   ui → ii, 　　　[悪]{わる}い → わりい
>   au → oo, 　　[買]{かう}た → こおた　　　　(Kansai dialect; written as こうた)
>   eu → oo, 　　でせう → でしょお　　(Standard pronunciation; written as でしょう)
>   ou → oo, 　　[泥]{どろ}[棒]{ぼう} → どろぼお　　(Standard pronunciation; written as どろぼう)
>   iu → uu, 　　[言]{い}う → ゆう　　　　　　(Standard pronunciation; written as いう)

All these follow the following phonological rule:

```
[α high][+ high, β back] → [α high, - low, β back]:
```

where

```
+---------------+--------+--------+
|               | - back | + back |
+---------------+--------+--------+
| + high, - low | i      | u      |
| - high, - low | e      | o      |
| - high, + low |        | a      |
+---------------+--------+--------+
```

Note: As far as I know, this rule was discovered by 窪薗晴夫.

Comment: Just to avoid possible confusion, “the person” is not the speaker, and こまけーんだよ means “You care too much.”

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto Thanks. That is what I meant. You made it clear.

Comment: You can't add `table`, `tr`, or `td` elements to this website as they aren't in the [allowed tag list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-overflow-server-fault-and-super-user)

Comment: @Troyen Thanks for fixing the table. Nice alignment.

Comment: @sawa I stumbled across [this site](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) while looking for a workaround and used it to generate the table.  Looks like it works well enough.

Comment: Wow, cypher's comment already solved my problem, but your answer is super useful beyond my original question! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for laying out the specifics of the underlying rule here so clearly, sawa. (Also, hey, Kubosono is the guy who wrote アクセントの法則! Great book, that.)