# What could コエーぞ mean in this context?

Tags: english-to-japanese

Hello im reading a comic where a girl is trying to get a guy to come to school, the guy brushes it off and replies　俺はコエーぞさっさと帰れ. From intuition, im getting the vibe of "Don't bother ( Ill pass), go home/ get lost" But what exactly does コエーぞ mean here. 怖い or かわいそう come to mind.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is じゃねぇか? What is its original form?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/18454/what-is-%e3%81%98%e3%82%83%e3%81%ad%e3%81%87%e3%81%8b-what-is-its-original-form)

Comment: See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3752/9831

Comment: Possible duplicate of [わからない vs わかね in My Boss My Hero](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/13069/%e3%82%8f%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84-vs-%e3%82%8f%e3%81%8b%e3%81%ad-in-my-boss-my-hero)

Answer (score 3):

I could well be wrong, but this parses out to me as slangy / informal for 怖【こわ】いぞ, i.e. "I'm scary / that's scary".

The *-ai* or *-oi* endings on various adjectives often collapse to *-ē* in informal speech, such as *sugoi* → *sugē*, *shiranai* → *shiranē*, and here, *kowai* → *koē* (since there isn't any *we* in modern Japanese).

Comment: 「俺は怖いぞ、さっさと帰れ」ですので I'm **scared** ~~ じゃなくて I'm **scary**, (so just) go home / get lost 「俺は怖いぞ、だからあっちへ行け」ってことです

Comment: Will upvote to balance the downvote. I think he got the main point. True, it is not "I'm scared" in this case, but the answerer not necessarily meant that "I'm scared" was the translation of the original sentence. I think he was talking about the adjective 怖い in general, although yeah, maybe an edit could help.

Comment: Ah, the joys of コピペ.  Editing momentarily.