# What かってぇ means here?

Tags: translation, meaning

> かってぇ！？ 剣じゃきかねーよ！

It's from the video game, the character tried to attack a monster but didn't hurt it much.

Is this かってぇ the same as かと? If so, why there's nothing before it?

Comment: 「[硬]{かた}い（固い？堅い？）」んじゃない？ https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3752/9831

Comment: My translation: 'It's freakin' tough! My sword don't hurt it at all!'