# What kind of grammar is てんじゃねえ?

Tags: negation

The character is trying to hit something I guess and says this

> ... れで、狙ってんじゃ、ねえんだから…………本、当……ッ

What kind of grammar is れで、狙ってんじゃ、ねえ exactly?

"Don't aim for that"? "I was not aiming for that"?

Answer (score 0):

- There is no such a word as れで. Perhaps the speaker was trying to say some longer phrase, but couldn't pronounce it all because they were surprised or exhausted. Someone who knows the correct context should be able to guess the right phrase. See the context yourself.
- 狙ってんじゃ is short of 狙ってるんじゃ, which is short for 狙っているのでは. See: [Why is the て-form being used before ん？](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/61958/5010)
- ねえ is ない. See: [What does こまけー mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3746/5010)

Both of your translation attempts are probably wrong, but I cannot provide the correct translation, either, since virtually no context is given.

Comment: So it's like  狙っているのではないだから_? Why is not the imperative negative "don't do x"?

Comment: @Bluegate I think that's where providing context would be more helpful.  Perhaps you could link to your source or provide a broader context of what was said or the scene or what happened before these words were spoken etc to help us make sense of how these words were used.

Comment: @Bluegate You dropped の. The sentence is equivalent to (○れで)狙っているのではないのだから.