# How does 時くれえ function here?

Tags: translation, contractions

> 最初にまみえた時くれえ
>
> 呆けてた方が可愛げがあって良いんじゃねえか

My rough understanding of the 2nd sentence is "You were so amazed that it was cute, so it's fine, right?"

I'm not sure how the first sentence works here.

If "最初にまみえた時" means "he time when you first me," What does it mean when you add くれえ?

For context, this is a scene where a guy teases a younger girl.

Comment: Hint: can you see a similarity between くれえ and じゃねえ in your second sentence?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/13073/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/1382/9831

Comment: 呆けてた方が可愛げがあって良いんじゃねえか doesn't mean "You were so amazed that it was cute, so it's fine, right?"

Comment: What does it mean then?

Comment: These two lines are one sentence. "Isn't it likable and nicer if [you are / she is] amazed at least when you've seen [her / you] for the first time?" (i.e., Staying cool even when seeing [her / you] for the first time would be too impersonal.) The context is lacking and I don't know who was amazed at who, but you should be able to tell that from the story. 可愛げがある is very hard to translate but it's basically not "cute".